# $ \int_{- \frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx $ any hints?

Tags: integration

I am struggling with following integral.

$$
\int_{- \frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx
$$

A small hint is enough.

Comment: Try the substitution $u=-x$ and use the fact that $$\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$$ for any $x>0$. You'll get $\pi^2/8$ as an answer.

Comment: Oh, this sounds great. I will try this and come back.

Comment: I have it. Very clever approach. Thank you!

Comment: Fun fact: You can replace $\tan(x)$ with any odd function $f$ in the exponent of $e$ and you'll always get $\pi^2/8$ as an answer.

Comment: @MatthewPilling We can also replace $e$ with any $a>0$, isn't?

Comment: @azif00 sure can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my approach by using the well-known property : $\arctan(f(x)) + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. One has:
$$\int_{- \frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx = \int_{- \frac{\pi}{4}}^{0} \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx+ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx$$
$$ \overset{t = - x} =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{-\tan(t)}) dt + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx$$ $$
$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{-1}(e^{-\tan(x)})+ \tan^{-1}(e^{\tan(x)}) dx= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} dx = \frac{\pi^2}{8} $$